# Showing QuerySelectMultipleField as checkbox

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2

I'm new in flask. When you use QuerySelectMultipleField in the jinja2 it shows as a drop-down select-box. but I don't like the drop-down and I prefer the options to be visible permanently without drop-down like  checkbox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have a queryselectmultiplefield for a field named 'answer'

```
{% for item in form.answer %}
  <div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.name }}" value="{{ item.data }}">
   {{ item.label }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```